# Why my project does not see the classes in referenced project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I can't resolve a problem, connected with classes and methods visibility of project who is attached to another project with references.. It's class library..

So I help expain this with screen shots.

1) [image]

So the `ExcelImportPlugin` is class, in referenced project, and it's in the same namespace with `BasePlugin` (why I have access to `ExcelImportPlugin` and not to `BasePlugin`?)

2) Object Browser for references:

[image]

As you can see both classes are in same namespace...

Because of this, code don't work, throwing file load error..

**EDIT**

additional code, so:

in `ExcelImportPlugin` class I use method of `BasePlugin` class

```
LoadXls<T>(path, Config, map);
```

I can't even Debug this method, because when I click F11 button to next step (into method) it throws:

`System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.7.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17'`

Comment: IO error is something *very* different from classes not being accessible. Are you getting an actual error? Please add it.

Comment: Also, please post the code that generates the error. That would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for reply, added additional code

Comment: You may need to add a package reference to `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` to the consuming project. On older versions of the framework, transitive dependency resolution doesn't always work like you might expect it to

Comment: Thank you @JamesFaix It worked now !